# PHP - Calling a function inside an object results in error: 'Call to a member function query() on integer in'

Tags: php, mysql, function, object, mysqli

I am having trouble calling a function inside a class `__construct`.

The function:

```
function dbcom_query($con,$query) {
    if (!$mysqli_result = $con->query($query)) dbcom_error();
    return $mysqli_result;
}
```

And the class:

```
class User {

    public $id;
    public $con;
    public $full_name;
    public $disp_name;

    public function __construct($id,$con) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM user_1;";
        $result = dbcom_query($con, $query);
        if ($result) {
            $usr_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $this->full_name = $usr_array['full_name'];
            $this->disp_name = $usr_array['disp_name'];
        }
    }
}
```

- I put the user_***1*** in the query to mitigate any doubt about how the query is being build. Otherwise, it would be $id.

But then I get this error, not sure what is going on:

**Call to a member function query() on integer in... 'x' line**

Where 'x'-line is: `$query = "SELECT * FROM user_1;";`

And, if I call this function `dbcom_query()` outside any object, it works fine.

**EDIT:** wow, I'm somewhat ashamed... I was calling `$user = new User($con,$id)"` - wrong parameter order. What a silly mistake. Sorry guys!

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM `user_1`";

Comment: Scope, Scope, scope

Comment: @Anant the `;` is unnecessary but I dont think it causes an error

Comment: You instantiated the object with `new User(42, 69)` or whatever - you DIDN'T pass in a db object, you passed in an integer. The query syntax itself is irrelevant. you're not executing it, because `$con` is an integer, not a DB object.

Comment: Thanks @Marc B - was indeed a mistake in the parameters order ($con, $id).

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling $con in the class, it is an integer. Make sure you pass in the values into the class correctly. You can rewrite the __constructor function to look like the following if you want to add error handling for it. Simply add the class name (Import namespace if there is one) like so:

```
public function __construct($id, ConnectionClass $con) {
```

Comment: Thank you @Andrew. It was indeed a integer, I messed up the parameters order when creating the object!

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss one part in the __construct method, saving the provided $con object inside the local $con value :

```
public function __construct($id,$con) {
        $this->con = $con;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM user_1;";
        $result = dbcom_query($con, $query);

        if ($result) {
            $usr_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $this->full_name = $usr_array['full_name'];
            $this->disp_name = $usr_array['disp_name'];
        }
```

But the real problem may come from the way you create the object User. Please provide the "new User($foo,$bar)" part of your code to see this point.

More generally, I suggest you define :

```
global $con;
```

in the begin of your script so this variable will be accessible from almost anywhere.

Massive edit, sorry :)

Comment: Thanks @technico for the help. When I was going to get the `new User` to show you, I saw it had the parameters inverted ($con, $id).

Comment: Nice :) One more step to the programmer's heaven for both of us !